# How do I call a plugin module that's loaded?

Tags: python, plugins, dynamic, module, loading

Either it's lack of sleep but I feel silly that I can't get this.  I have a plugin, I see it get loaded but I can't instantiate it in my main file:

```
from transformers.FOMIBaseClass import find_plugins, register
find_plugins()
```

Here's my FOMIBaseClass:

```
from PluginBase import MountPoint
import sys
import os

class FOMIBaseClass(object):
    __metaclass__ = MountPoint

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def init_plugins(self):
        pass

def find_plugins():
    plugin_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    plugin_files = [x[:-3] for x in os.listdir(plugin_dir) if x.endswith("Transformer.py")]
    sys.path.insert(0, plugin_dir)
    for plugin in plugin_files:
        mod = __import__(plugin)
```

Here's my MountPoint:

```
class MountPoint(type):
    def __init__(cls,name,bases,attrs):
        if not hasattr(cls,'plugins'):
            cls.plugins = []
        else:
            cls.plugins.append(cls)
```

I see it being loaded:

```
# /Users/carlos/Desktop/ws_working_folder/python/transformers/SctyDistTransformer.pyc matches /Users/carlos/Desktop/ws_working_folder/python/transformers/SctyDistTransformer.py
import SctyDistTransformer # precompiled from /Users/carlos/Desktop/ws_working_folder/python/transformers/SctyDistTransformer.pyc
```

But, for the life of me, I can't instantiate the 'SctyDistTransformer' module from the main file.  I know I'm missing something trivial.  Basically, I want to employ a class loading plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To dymically load Python modules from arbitrary folders use imp module:

http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html

Specifically the code should look like:

```
   mod = imp.load_source("MyModule", "MyModule.py")
   clz = getattr(mod, "MyClassName")
```

Also if you are building serious plug-in architecture I recommend using Python eggs and entry points:

http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/Using+Entry+Points+to+Write+Plugins

https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/main.py#L104

Comment: Out of curiosity, what makes one better than the other?

Comment: Python packages (eggs) can be separately distributed. Python has standard mechanism for discovering these eggs and third party plug-ins can be simply uploaded to pypi.python.org and installed for your application using easy_install / pip. The downside is that Python egg boilerplate must be managed instead simply tossing .py files around.

Comment: Also Python eggs declare dependencies and if your plug-ins may use third party Python libraries the egg is the only sensible way to distribute plug-ins.